# Initializing jquery ui plugins using live or on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to initialize `jquery ui button plugin` using  `live` or `on`. Means something like :

```
          $('button').live("which event", function() { $(this).button(); });
```

But i don't know the event which i can use in this place. I tried `load` and `ready` but not works. Then i tried `custom event` also :

```
          $('button').live("event", function() { $(this).button(); });
          $('button').trigger('event');
```

This also not works.Help me out please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that button is present on dom ready then :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').button();
});
```

If it's created afterwards :

```
$('<button />').appendTo('body').button();
```